# Помогите с Upload Google Drive API Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, google-drive

**Вот интерфейс для Retrofit2:**

```
public interface OAuthServerIntf {

....
@POST("upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
@Multipart
Call<JsonObject> uploadFileMutil(
        @Header("Authorization") String authToken,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part metaPart,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part dataPart);

}
```

Вот где я вызываю:

```
public void onActivityResult(...) {
   ....
 MultipartBody.Part filePart = 
    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), fileBody);
 Call<JsonObject> request =  
    server.uploadFileMutil(oauthToken.getAccessToken(),filePart);
 request.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>(){...});

}
```

**oauthToken.getAccessToken()**-получаем токен

**MultipartBody.Part filePart** - файл, который хочу отправить на сервер

В общем как проводить запрос 
и что эти за 2 параметра **metaPart** и **dataPart**?

Читал, что **токен** нужно приводить к типу **Bearer**, как это сделать???